# Trying to install Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

I had office 2010 installed on my computer when I purchased it.  What I believed to be a trial version ended and I uninstalled the 2010 version.  I located my product key for this and now I can't find anyway to re-install 2010 and use my product key.  Can anyone help?

thanks,

Comment: Getting help / ref from https://www.office.com/ shall do. May be they have some undocumented steps needed to be done during the installation.

Answer (score 1):

You could download it from the internet then reinstall it that way- but if you literally JUST uninstalled it (very recently) then you might want to do a system restore and get it back that way.

Comment: Download from where exactly?

Comment: From here:

https://www7.downloadoffice2010.microsoft.com/row/registerkey.aspx?ref=pkc&culture=en-CA

Answer (score 1):

Try this link - http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/buy/using-the-product-key-card-FX101853163.aspx

If you have a genuine product key then you will be able to download it. Hope this works.